# sql using pivot improving performance

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table, query-performance

i am using pivot on my first time.
i don't know how it is working so i don't know how to calculate what would be more efficient.

i want to select various fields in addition to the aggreagated fields,
and use some joins to other table.

where should i locate it? should i put the other fields and joins in the pivot source table?

```
select dc_id, Mosah_code, **field_x, field_y**, [31] , [32] ,[33], [34]
from (select dc.dc_id, dc.Mosah_code, **field_x, field_y**, dp.Sapak_code, dp.DC_Pprice_after_discount from DcnezekCloudAuction dc
left join DcnezekCloudAuctionParts dp on dc.dc_id = dp.DC_ID and dp.Mosah_code = dc.Mosah_code) as S
pivot
(
sum (DC_Pprice_after_discount)
FOR Sapak_Code IN ([31], [32], [33], [34])
)AS P​
```

Or should I place pivot results in a table and join to itself and other table

```
select * from DcnezekCloudAuction dc1
left join 
(select dc_id, Mosah_code,  [31] , [32] ,[33], [34]
from (select dc.dc_id, dc.Mosah_code, dp.Sapak_code, dp.DC_Pprice_after_discount from DcnezekCloudAuction dc
left join DcnezekCloudAuctionParts dp on dc.dc_id = dp.DC_ID and dp.Mosah_code = dc.Mosah_code) as S
pivot
(
sum (DC_Pprice_after_discount)
 FOR  Sapak_Code IN ([31], [32], [33], [34])
)AS P) piv on dc1.dc_id = piv.dc_id and dc1.Mosah_code = piv.Mosah_code
```

i will just say that in the future i will add where close to the table DcnezekCloudAuction if it matters...

Comment: Just test the two options.

Comment: They'll probably end up performing the same; go for the more readable one. I tend to pivot just what I need and join extra data on after the pivot is done

Comment: Caius Jard - thanks!!!